# AudioClip.SetData(samples,0) not working loading sample data from json file in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, get, set, audioclip

I am trying to Set audioclip samples previously saved using audioclip.GetData from a json file.
The Audio data is present in my json file but it seems not to work when Loading this file and setting up the audioclip data using SetData:

In my Load function:
I am Instantiating a prefab that contains the component AudioSource: audioFB.
Then I want to set up the clip using:

```
audioFB.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip.SetData(qc.clipData, 0);
```

However I do have this error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object when doing so.

On the other hand if I directly Load an audio file from Resources folder, it does work.

Am I not using SetData correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you check that audioFB is not `null`, also that the `GetComponent` isn't returning null as well?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
Yes I checked audioFB, I can set other attributes and it works fine. As I said, even if I add an audioclip from my resources folder it works, but using SetData it returns the object reference error.

Same goes for GetComponent, not returning null.

Comment: Did you also check that your AudioSource.clip isn't null?

Comment: When I instantiate the prefab with its Audio Source component, It has a predefined sound.
I am trying to use SetData to modify this predefined sound's data, am I doing it the wrong way?

PS: If I do it this way, I don't get the error but my sound is not modified/changed with the new data I want to SET. However without pre-adding the sound I do get the object reference error.

Comment: Possibly, from what I see there are a few places this can be going wrong they are: audioFB is null, the AudioSource is null, the AudioSource.clip is null(It could still be being created by the time this method is called?), or qc is null.  I would just write a quick check on each of those and have it print out which is null.

Comment: I finally managed to make it work when I am adding a "silence" sound (0 amplitude) in my instantiated object clip. Then I use SetData(qc.clipData,0).

Now my issue is that for each object I make, I always get the same sound even if qc.clipData is different for each of them..